# looping between two vectors for meeting three conditions

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a csv file containing 4 columns of data. I need to select the first column from the csv file which I do like this:

```
file1<-read.csv("file1.csv",header=TRUE)
x<-file[,1]
```

The first column contains (x, here) contains row numbers.

```
x
5
10
54
177
178
182
183
184
185
203
204
205
206
207
208
```

Now there is another csv file which contains a single column of 365 rows of data

```
y<-read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE)

y
0
2.3
0.5
21
0
.
.
.
9.5 #total 365 numbers
```

This is what I intend to do:

1) From x, chose the first number (which is 5)

2) In y, select the corresponding 5th data point (which is 0) and 4 data point prior to it (which are 21,0.5,2.3,0), then test the following condition respectively

Condition 1: From the 5 data points, if the three out of five are > 0, then print 5 (result of step 1)

Condition 2: If all four of five are >0, then print 5 again

Condition 3: If all of five are >0, then print 5 again

However, if out of three conditions, only the first two are met and third one is not met, then select the second number from x (10 in this case) and again choose the corresponding 10th data point in y and four data points prior to it (6th,7th,8th and 9th) and evaluate them for the third condition (i.e. if all the five numbers - 6th, 7th, 8th,9th and 10th are > 0, I do not need to evaluate the first and second condition which are already met by the previous number from x),then save 10 and stop.

This sounds quite complicated for a feeble mind of mine (as seen by my reputation) and was hoping someone can tell me how to do this in R.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a while loop.

```
file1 <- data.frame(x=seq(5, 205, by=5))
file1
x <- file1[, 1]

set.seed(123)
file2 <- data.frame(y=rnorm(365))
y <- file2[, 1]

# flags for each condition
cond1 <- FALSE
cond2 <- FALSE
cond3 <- FALSE

k <- 0
while(!cond3) {  
  k <- k + 1

  # select first number
  num <- x[k]

  # select all y's up to data point
  all.y <- y[(num-4):num]

  # number of positive values
  chk.pos <- length(which(all.y > 0))

  # condition 1: check if 3 of 5 are positive
  cnt <- 0
  if (!cond1 & chk.pos >= 3) {
    cnt <- cnt + 1
    cond1 <- TRUE
    print(num)
  }

  # condition 2:  check if 4 of 5 are positive
  if (!cond2 & chk.pos >= 4) {
    cnt <- cnt + 1
    cond2 <- TRUE
    print(num)
  }

  # condition 3:  check if 5 of 5 are positive
  if (!cond3 & chk.pos == 5) {
    cnt <- cnt + 1
    cond3 <- TRUE
    print(num)
  }

}
```

for me returns

```
[1] 5
[1] 15
[1] 70
```